# capture segfault with lldb on OS X

Tags: macos, lldb

An OS X binary runs into a segfault when invoked under Yosemite (prints "Segmentation fault: 11" on stderr), but when invoked using lldb, no segfault occurs, and the program ends with error code 0.

Do you have any idea what the reason might be, that the segfault doesn't occur when using lldb? Is there any way to trigger it there (and stop execution when it occurs, so some debugging is possible)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running your program separately and attaching to it.  If your binary is called `a.out`, you would use the `process attach --waitfor` command like this:

```
term1$ lldb
(lldb) pr a -w a.out

term2$ a.out
```

lldb will poll the process table repeatedly until `a.out` starts up - when it sees the process, it will attach to it.  In the lldb terminal, `c` (`continue`) the process execution.

Alternatively, you may have a crash report from your process segfaulting in `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/`.  This will show you the backtrace at the point where your binary crashed.  You may also want to open `Console.app` and see if any messages are being logged to console at the point where it crashes.

Comment: At least on recent LLDB versions on macOS, the syntax is `pr a -w -n a.out`.